# My sitecore page is redirecting to a 404 page, but it exists in preview and is also verified as published

Tags: redirect, iis, sitecore, http-status-code-404

I have a single page which I built from the same blocks as other pages in the same category, which do work. This page redirects to the 404 page.

I checked to make sure the page was published- it is.

I am able to preview the page in the Experience area and it looks good.

From what I can tell, no other 301s have been set up to override this.

What else can I check?

Comment: What is the url of that page? Are there any 2 or 3 letter words which could be considered by Sitecore as language names? have you tried renaming that item and republishing it and checking if it works after you do this?

Comment: Have you checked your log files?

Comment: Are all the dependencies published?  Does it have a layout set?

Comment: Thanks @Jen. Yes it was actually a dependency to a deleted element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were dependencies that were on the page that no longer existed. Apparently, whoever cloned the page used an older (previously working) page, which no longer worked.

The specific element in question was an object reference to an image in a gallery.

We removed the element in the editor, published the page, and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Try Checking your log files. There are additional information about what is happening.